# How to show detailed view of phonebook?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am trying to show a detailed view of the contacts stored in a phonebook. The PhoneBook(id, name) is one of my models which is a foreign key to model Contact(id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, phone_book).

In my index page, there is a button which opens the phone book. After that, I want it such that the user may click on a phone book and the detailed view(first_name, last_name, phone_number) would be shown to them.

In view.py, I have a function which captures all the phonebook, passes it through context(dict). In my template, I have used a for loop to go through all the phonebooks and print them.

I am unable to direct the page to a detailed view. How do I get the phonebook the user clicked on? And how to direct the page from ./view to ./detail

```py
# view.py

def view_phone_book(request):
    all_phone_books = PhoneBook.objects.all()

    context = {
        'all_phone_books': all_phone_books
    }

    return render(request, "CallCenter/view_phone_book.html", context)

def detailed_view_phone_book(request):
    all_contacts = Contact.objects.all().filter(phone_book=phone_book_user_clicked_on)
    context = {
        'all_contacts': all_contacts
    }
    return render(request, "CallCenter/detailed_view_phone_book.html", context)
```

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('create/', create_phone_book, name="create"),
    path('add/', add_to_phone_book, name="add"),
    path('view/', view_phone_book, name="view"),
    path('detail/', detailed_view_phone_book, name="detailed_view")
]
```

```py
# models.py
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
    """
        Model to store customer to a phone book
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Contact(models.Model):

    """
        Model to store customer to a phone book.
    """

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=False, unique=True)
    phone_book = models.ForeignKey(PhoneBook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

```
<!--view_phone_book.html-->
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Phone Book</th>
   </tr>

   {% for phone_book in all_phone_books %}
     <tr>
       <form method="get" action="../detail/"><td><a href="">{{ phone_book }}</a> </td></form>
     </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>


<!--detailed_view_phone_book.html-->
<table>
<tr>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Phone Number</th>
   </tr>
   {% for phone_detail in all_phone_detail %}
    <tr>
       <form>
           <td>{{ phone_detail.first_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ phone_detail.last_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ phone_detail.phone_number }}</td>
        </form>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I am unable to go from ./view to ./detail. Also, how would I know which phone book the user clicked on?

Comment: You could use js to load detailview and then render it on top of your phonebooks. If you just want to use template only, it also can but the cost is very high, you have to create like everything detail modal for each phonebook so that when click to a button then you just show the corresponding modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on how to make it work, and I'm answering it so that if anyone gets stuck in, it can help themselves.

```py
# views.py 

def view_phone_book(request):
    all_phone_books = PhoneBook.objects.all()

    context = {
        'all_phone_books': all_phone_books
    }

    return render(request, "CallCenter/view_phone_book.html", context)

def detailed_view_phone_book(request, phone_book_id):
    try:
        all_contacts = Contact.objects.filter(pk=phone_book_id)
    except Contact.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("PhoneBook Does Not Exist!")
    context = {
        'all_contacts': all_contacts
    }
    return render(request, "CallCenter/detailed_view_phone_book.html", context)
```

```py
#urls.py 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('create/', create_phone_book, name="create"),
    path('add/', add_to_phone_book, name="add"),
    path('campaign/', create_campaign, name="create-campaign"),
    path('view/', view_phone_book, name="view-phone-book"),
    path('detail/<int:phone_book_id>', detailed_view_phone_book, name="detail-view-phone-book"),
```

```
<!--view_phone_book.html-->
<body>
    {% for phone_book in all_phone_books%}
        <a href="{% url 'detail-view-phone-book' phone_book.id%}">{{ phone_book }}</a>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Back To Home</a>
</body>


<!--detailed_view_phone_book.html-->
{% if all_contacts %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
            {% for contact in all_contacts %}
                <tr>
                    <form>
                        <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ contact.phone_number }}</td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% endif %}


<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Back To Home</a>
```

I watched the [Brain's CS50 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjAMRnCu-84), which helped me. I'll suggest you do the same. He explains the concepts in a beginner-friendly way.